# one mxd per region or many mxd's per map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I am working somewhere where they insist on using one mxd per region, in this mxd there is every layer required to make maps (about 10 per region). I find it tedious because you have to turn layers on and off and recreate the legend, and I find that since each region has the same layers if someone has another mxd open I can't edit layers.

What is the best practice? the idea was that there were too many mxd's being created, but I always thought it was better to have one mxd per map.

---

we can't do data driven pages because each map has about 3 layouts and requires some fiddling that can't be automated.

Comment: Another problem is that if a change is made to one layer (eg the symbology, the label font, etc) then you'll need to make that change in _every_ MXD which uses that layer. Data-driven pages definitely sounds like the way to go

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say "each map has about 3 layouts" because in ArcMap there is only one layout per map.  I suspect your question would benefit from some pictures that illustrate what you are trying to describe in words.  I also suspect you may be using "map" to refer to map series.

Comment: I mean, each map has 3 bookmarked layouts that you use depending on what map you are creating. They are just different scales.

Comment: I think data driven pages would only work when labels were consistent over all regions

Answer (score 4):

What you describe sounds to me like a use case for [Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003m000000).

If they do not meet 100% of your requirements then they are well integrated with ArcPy to complete the necessary map automation.